# Clarification on Cartesian tensor products

Tags: tensors

Suppose I have a tensor of second order. If I take the tensor product of it and itself, the result is a tensor of second order right? I am asking this since I think that although the tensor product of 2 first order tensors is a second order tensor, the tensor product of 2 second order tensors in general results in a second order tensor whose components themselves are second order tensors.

Comment: **No.** The tensor product of a $(r,s)$ tensor and a $(p,q)$ tensor is a $(r+p,s+q)$ tensor.

Comment: So it should be a fourth order tensor?

Comment: $(V\otimes V)\otimes(V\otimes V)\cong V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V$